# add java methods to code

Tags: java, function, methods, programming-languages

I start study programming, I made a simple code in java,

is a contest, every participant make bites to an apples, so the participant that bites are more weight wins!

but!! I need add in all code with java methods, functions... you know

please run the code for you understand more

any help? really thanks!

```
import java.io.*;

   class reality_show_methods{

public static void main(String[] args)throws java.io.IOException{

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintStream out = System.out;

    // VARIABLES
    int     counterParticipants = 1, numPart, numBoc;

    double  weightBoc, weightBocTotalMayor = 0;

    String  namePart, nameParticipantWinner = "";                                                                                                                     

    // SETUP
    out.print("Number of Participants ......................... ");
    numPart = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    out.print("Number of Participants Bites: ....... ");
    numBoc = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

    // START
    while (counterParticipants <= numPart) {

        out.print("\nParticipant Name #" + counterParticipants + " ...................... ");
        namePart = in.readLine();

        int countBoc = 1;                                                     
        double weightBocTotal = 0;                                               

        while (countBoc <= numBoc) {

            out.print("Bite weight #" + countBoc + " of the Participant " + namePart + ": ");
            weightBoc = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());

            weightBocTotal = weightBocTotal + weightBoc;

            countBoc++;
        }

        if (weightBocTotalMayor < weightBocTotal) {                                
            weightBocTotalMayor = weightBocTotal;
            nameParticipantWinner = namePart;
    }

    counterParticipants++;
}

// SHOW WINNER
out.println("\nParticipant Winner: ................... " + nameParticipantWinner + " with Total Weight: " + weightBocTotalMayor);

} 

     }
```

Comment: Max is right - you need to give us more information on what you want to know. What do you think is wrong with the code and how do you think we can help?

Comment: I'd like to guess first: do you mean you have to separate the codes into methods instead of having everything in main?

Comment: @LeleDumbo, yes that I need separate my code in methods, I mean make the same! that I do but using methods, I think that is easy for an expert, but I have one month of start programming

Comment: Isolating some of the code-blocks to methods doesn't clarify the code much at all. I supposed you could imagine that all the comment sections could be isolated to their own methods (InitalizeVariables(), SetupGame()...), but adding a simple Participant object would be much better. Objects weren't mentioned then?

Comment: This is not a "do my homework for me" site. And reduce your code to the minimum before posting!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
public static void myFunction()
{
    // blah blah
}
```

Comment: well... I know that... but is not simple to me reemplace the // blah // blah with real code

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would help you.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class BiteContest {

    private class Participant{
        private String name;
        private double biteWeight;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public double getBiteWeight() {
            return biteWeight;
        }
        public void setBiteWeight(double biteWeight) {
            this.biteWeight = biteWeight;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Participant> participants = new ArrayList<Participant>();

    int numBoc;

    BufferedReader in;
    PrintStream out;

    BiteContest(){
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        out = System.out;
    }
    void addParticepents() throws IOException
    {
        boolean noMoreParticipants = false;

        while( !noMoreParticipants )
        {
            out.print("Participant Name : ");
            String name = in.readLine();

            Participant participant = new Participant();
            participant.setName(name);
            participant.setBiteWeight(0);

            participants.add( participant );

            out.print("Want to add more participants [Y/N]: ");
            String input = in.readLine();
            //Get first character.
            input = input.substring(0,1);

            noMoreParticipants = "y".equalsIgnoreCase(input)?false:true;
        }
    }
    void takeBiteCount() throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        out.print("\nNumber of Participants Bites : ");
        numBoc = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
    void contest() throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        out.print( "\n\n------CONTEST STARTS------" );
        for( Participant participant : participants )
        {
            out.print( "\n\n------------" );
            out.print( "\nTaking Bites for " + participant.getName() + "\n" );
            for( int i = 0; i < numBoc; i++ )
            {
                out.print("Bite weight #" + (i+1) + " of the Participant " + participant.getName() + " : ");
                double weightBoc = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
                participant.setBiteWeight( participant.getBiteWeight() + weightBoc );
            }
        }
    }
    String getTheWinner(){
        Collections.sort( participants, new Comparator<Participant>() {
            public int compare(Participant o1, Participant o2) {
                return (int)(o2.getBiteWeight() - o1.getBiteWeight());
            }
        } );
        // Client at the top will be the winner. 
        return participants.get(0).getName();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BiteContest contest = new BiteContest();

        try {
            contest.addParticepents();
            contest.takeBiteCount();
            contest.contest();
            String winner = contest.getTheWinner();

            System.out.println( "\n\n-------------------------\n" +
                    "The winner is : " + winner );

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```